# How to make foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

i'm trying to make an sql create table but I fail to make a foreign key.

My code :

```
Db::getInstance()->execute('

      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `'._DB_PREFIX_.'sondage`(
      `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `question` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY(`id`)) ENGINE='._MYSQL_ENGINE_.' default CHARSET=utf8')

|| !Db::getInstance()->execute('

      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `'._DB_PREFIX_.'sondage_reponse`(
      `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `champ1` int(4) NOT NULL,
      `champ2` int(4) NOT NULL,
      `champ3` int(4) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY(`id`)) ENGINE='._MYSQL_ENGINE_.' default CHARSET=utf8')


|| !Db::getInstance()->execute('

 INSERT INTO '._DB_PREFIX_.'sondage_reponse (champ1,champ2,champ3)
 VALUES (0,0,0)')
```

I want to make id from "sondage" foreign key in "sondage_reponse".I've tryed :

```
 ALTER TABLE ps_sondage_reponse
            ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_id_sdg(id)
            REFERENCES sondage(id)')
```

But Prestashop can't add the foreign key.

Thx

Comment: it'd be helpful if you stripped out all the pointless getinstance stuff and shows us the actual query strings. is your `_DB_PREFIX_` really `ps_`? **HOW** are you unable to add the FK? you get a syntax error? no such table? no such field? Are you using an engine which supports FKs?

Answer (score 0):

i'd say to try this :

```
ALTER TABLE ps_sondage_reponse
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_sdg
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES sondage(id)
```